# Asterisk: ODBC options not available in menuselect

Tags: linux, asterisk, odbc

I have done `yum install unixODBC` and `yum install freetds`, but when I try `make menuselect` while installing Asterisk, none of the ODBC options are available. func_odbc and res_odbc show up with an XXX and I can't select them. How do I get ODBC included for my Asterisk build?

Answer (score 1):

You need -devel options if you want devel workaround(compile from source).

So just install unixODBC-devel (or unixODBC-dev if you have debian/ubuntu) and it will be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done 'yum install unixODBC-devel', but ODBC options are still unavailable in make menuselect (ODBC options show us as XXX). I'm not sure what you mean by "devel workaround".

Comment: You have reconfigure after that again. ./configure process only change that,not menuconfig.

Comment: If you have no skill for build from source, just use packages, will be much less issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I removed unixODBC, installed unixODBC-devel, ran ./configure again, but still don't have any ODBC options in menuselect. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check config.log for ODBC word.

Comment: What am I looking for in config.log? I do see "ac_cv_lib_odbc_SQLConnect=yes" if that helps.

Comment: @arheops - Great advice, why bother learning at all?  You had the skill to build from source at birth, I take it?

Comment: In this case no real need to build asterisk. Packages will work just fine.